# How to configure URL Segment (typo3 10.2.0)

Tags: bootstrap-4, typo3, typo3-10.x

I installed typo3 10.2.0 and set up 'Entry Point' in the 'Sites' menu to point to the working directory of the site. The first web page appears correctly (http://127.0.0.1/typo3_src-10.2.0/), but the internal links that are in "http://127.0.0.1/typo3_src-10.2.0/pages/2-columns" do not work. I have a "Page Not Found"!

Do you have an idea ? I installed the bootstrap package by default.

Best regards

Comment: What kind of web server are you using? If apache: do you have mod_rewrite enabled and is there an .htaccess file? See here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#web-server-environment

Comment: This is apache2 and the mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best of you do not set up the system into subdirectory. TYPO3 typically runs at the top of the site and many components assume it is on the top of the site. I've seen many questions and issues when people tries to run TYPO3 in a subdirectory. It is possible but it typically causes all kind of issues.

You can use tools like [ddev](https://www.ddev.com/) to make any number of local web servers with proper names (like http://typo3-test.ddev.site/, for example). ddev supports TYPO3 for quick and effortless setup. Then you need to follow TYPO3 installation instructions to use TYPO3 with composer. Typically it just works after that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers ! I had mod_rewrite activated but it was not well configured in sites-available / 000-default.conf, it was necessary to add the following line:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Best regards